# basic javascript validation for two identical forms on one page

Tags: javascript, validation

The site I'm building requires two identical forms on each page that sends the data to the same place, one form in the sidebar, and the other form in the footer. All I am trying for is light weight javascript that will kick out an error message if the user tries to submit the form when any or all of the required fields are left blank. Here's my issue:

Everything works as I intended for the sidebar form, however the javascript isn't treating the form placed in the footer as it does the sidebar form. When all form requirements are satisfied within form #2, it doesn't process the data and only shows the error message because I'm assuming it thinks the form is blank since the other form is blank.

I understand that there's likely a conflict of interest going on and the javascript engine is confused due to the input id's being exactly the same (they nned to be for this project since it involves salesforce). I already have bullet proof spam protection built into the php file that processes the form data, I just need some basic client-side validation to prevent the user from submitting the forms with any missing 'required' data. Like I said, everything works as I want it to with the first form, but not at all with the second. Can anyone help me with this because I don't really know where to start. I'm still relatively new to working with javascript so I apologize if what I have written is mess.

form #1 (in the sidebar)

```
$("#messageSent").hide();
$("#form1").submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    var fname     = $('#first_name').val();
    var lname     = $('#last_name').val();
    var phone     = $('#phone').val();
    var email     = $('#email').val();
    var condition = $('#condition').val();
    var relationship = $('#relationship').val();
    var inquiry = $('#inquiry').val();

    if(fname && lname && phone && email && condition && relationship && inquiry){
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: $(this).attr('action'),
           data: $("#form1").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               data = $("#messageSent").fadeIn(),
               $("#form1").fadeOut()
           }
         });
    } else {
    alert("You must complete the required fields before submitting the form.")
    return false;
    }
});
```

form #2 (in the footer section)

```
$('#messageSent-bottom').hide();
$("#form2").submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    var fname     = $('#first_name').val();
    var lname     = $('#last_name').val();
    var phone     = $('#phone').val();
    var email     = $('#email').val();
    var condition = $('#condition').val();
    var relationship = $('#relationship').val();
    var inquiry = $('#inquiry').val();

    if(fname && lname && phone && email && condition && relationship && inquiry){
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: $(this).attr('action'),
           data: $("#form2").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data){
               data = $("#messageSent-bottom").fadeIn(),
               $("#form2").fadeOut()
           }
         });
    } else {
    alert("You must complete the required fields before submitting the form.")
    return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use $('#the-id'), it only grabs the first one on the page (since you really shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id).

You could try adding something like the following:

```
var fname = $(this).find('#first_name').val();
```

This will keep it in the context of the current form. Though I would probably just prefix the ids since you already have separate submit functions.